# How to sample points along a bezier path at set proportions along the path length

Tags: bezier, polyline

I have a path that is made up of a combination of quadratic bezier curves and straight line segments. The path may be not necessarily be continuous as the path may also contain "MOVETO" statements that set the current start of the line to another point in space.

I would like to, given a list of values in the interval [0, 1], sample points along this path. The list of values provided represent the proportion of the path travelled.

The way I thought to do this was to convert the list of "global" values to local t values from which I can interpolate along the curves/lines. However, I am having issues with this approach.

For example, if the list of "global" values was

```
[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
```

and the list of distances traveled along the line between the start and end of curves was

```
[0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.55, 0.7, 0.75, 0.9, 0.9, 1]
```

the list of "local" t values would be,

```
[0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.33, 0.33, 1]
```

Is there a simple way I can do this? I feel like I am making this needlessly complicated.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Simple? Absolutely. "Using a simple formula"? There is not.

Longer answer: what you're trying to do is called reparameterising the curve by arclength (turning the non-linear equation of time, yielding distance, into a linear equation of distance, yielding time) which unfortunately is symbolically impossible for any Bezier curve except for one: the already linear Bezier curve (so reparameterizing is kind of meaningless for that case).

There are quite a few papers on the subject that try to identify cases in which you sort of can, or try to solve that problem by tackling it piecewise, but: when you have a computer, really the most straight forward way is to just "try more t values than you want, throw away the ones you don't need", e.g. https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing with the idea being you compute the arclength for your curve at a number of t values along the curve (say, 100 of them) and store the "distance d along the curve maps to time value t" information in a lookup table. You then *ignore* the actual curve itself and then find t values based on that lookup table:

say you need the t value for distance 0.522 along the curve. Your LUT has d0.52=t0.44 and d0.53=t.0.45, so you guess: d0.522= 0.8 * 0.44 + 0.2 * 0.45 (e.g. linear ratio) and get t=0.442, and then you compute the arc length for that t value in the same way you computed the arc length to build your LUT

if it's "close enough" (based on some small error like "less than a pixel off") you're done. If it's not, you can now start correcting that t value up or down by small fractions (either just walking up/down the values, or using a binary search, which is really easily implemented).